# Why does pulling the power cord and then pressing the power button down solve the Bluetooth issue?

Tags: power-supply, bluetooth

Recently I had an issue with Bluetooth on my laptop. It didn't show up in settings and did not work. So I pulled the psu and press power button for 30+ seconds and it solved my problem. As far as I know, it just frees the motherboard from any power but it has to do with the Bluetooth trouble?

Comment: Correlation is not causation

Answer (score 0):

This is related to the universal "Have you tried rebooting?" Technique.
Most hardware sets itself to some known state on power-off or reboot.
Many times this fixes thing.

It does not find root cause for the problem but it does allow life to go on.

If the laptop is connecting to Bluetooth devices then they are reset and the communication reconnects.